# Using tensorflow with nodejs library for machine learning models

Tags: python, c++, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have read that different libraries are availbale for Tensorflow. (In Python, C++, javascript).

"Tensorflow.js is a javascript lib for training and deploying machine learning models in Node.js".
so does it mean that **Tensorflow supports Nodejs also ?**

I don't have much idea about js/javascript/nodejs.

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. See here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs

It even works in browser. See section `Develop ML in the Browser` in above link.

Comment: Thanks Ashish,
So, I can use nodejs for tensorflow, but on tensorflow official website (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference) i can see that under section "Supported platforms > Linux ", for running Inference on TF lite models available APIs is only in Python & C++. So, node is not supported for running the inference right ?
Basically my ultimate goal is developing Tensorflow for Linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation I found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/nodejs) says it is possible.

check `import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs-node'`

Comment: We can use Nodejs based library for the implementation of Tensorflow. Still after some research i have found that it would be advisable to go either with Python/C++. Those two libraries have a wwll support online as well as documnented things/help available for the help.